# How does one specify the main test file in testcafe? (Aka other ways to avoid 'fixture is not defined')

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to avoid the testcafe 'fixture is not defined'-error while importing test into another testfile and found the advice to specify my testcafe main test file in the CLI. Sadly I couldn't find any guide on how to do that in the documentation ... is there any CLI command for it?

While trying to find a solution for my 'fixture is not defined'-error I found [this solution](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3940) to the problem. It might be a bit different for me though since I'm using Typescript.

Searching in [the testcafe CLI docu](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html) didn't get me any further though.

I do have an `All_functions.testcafe.ts` where I got a collection of functions I want to reuse. Then I got a `Functions_Library.ts` and a `ListViewSpec.ts` from which I import functions and objects.
In my `Special_Test.testcafe.ts` I want to include the tests of the `all_functions.testcafe.ts` file, but getting them into a function, exporting that, importing at Special and then using is throwing me an error.

I'm doing it like this:

```
#All_functions.testcafe.ts

export default function generalTests() {
 // here come the test
}
```

```
#Special_Test.testcafe.js

import generalTests from '../all_functions.testcafe.ts';

listViews.forEach(listView => {

generalTests();

test() {} // this works fine
```

Trying it only throw's

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error

ReferenceError: fixture is not defined
```

Which makes me think of how to define the test as the main test in the CLI.

Comment: I've tried running tests in a similar environment and it works properly. Could you please try to reproduce this behavior with the following code example [testcafe-test-import](https://gist.github.com/Dmitry-Ostashev/da4ae595b88f1c245709bb789de35de8)? Run the main test file by the following command: testcafe chrome test.ts. Tests will be executed.

Comment: @Dimitry ... I'm on leave for a few days, will check it out once I'm back on monday. Thanks for your reply~

Comment: @Dimitry ... Your code works fine for mine! (Though it's ought to be``mport runAllTests from``I guess?

Will need to check where i went wrong in my code ...
Glad to know it works though!! Thanks :)

Comment: You're right, it's a typo. I'm happy to assist you.